# Asp.net mvc3 web site extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Want to implement this feature but how?

We know that stack overflow has been written in asp.net mvc3 from [what was stack overflow built with?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) .

When i am here i have never noticed .aspx extension in URL, but it should be there as all asp.net web site has it. it may be the silly point to ask. but i am very curious to know how to exactly hide the extension for asp.net web site.

Comment: Not all ASP.Net web pages must end in aspx.  There are also ashx, asmx, and ascx pages, not to mention the fact that you can use url rewriting or page routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must read about URL Rewriting 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

or use this rewrite software
http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/

Another good blog on the same can be accessed at 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 you might consider going through 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC you can map routes; which basically means you can map any incoming request to a URL to a given action...Take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) to find out more.